# Using flexdashoboard in R: how to make 1 one click give me an output, 2 clicks other output and 3 clicks other output in a ggplot chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, flexdashboard

I have to make `Action`button gives me 3 outputs:

- All outputs will be in dots on ggplot chart.
- when I click one time the dot will be on `(30,58)` point on my ggplot chart.
- when I click two times the dot will be on `(40,68)` point on my ggplot chart.
- when I click three times the dot will be on `(50,78)` point on my ggplot chart.

Bellow is my code bellow:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)

dataset <- diamonds
```

Column {data-width=150}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
actionButton("action", "Action")
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
 
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = tibble(x = c(30,40,50),y = c(58,68,78)), aes(x =x, y = y))

```

### Chart C

```{r}
reactive({
  input$action
})
```
````

As you can see Im a begginer. I just need to understand how to link the idea of n-clicks and n-outputs in flexdashboard/shiny.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but we can use `flexdashboard` similarly to `shiny` like this:

Note: I changed the color of the points instead of showing them individually because if not the point will look like it doesn't move.

````
---
title: "Press Three Times The Button"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)
```

```{r}
shinyApp(
  ui = fillPage(
    fillCol(
      flex = c(NA, 1),
      inputPanel(
        actionButton("action", "Action")
      ),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    data <- tibble(x = c(30, 40, 50), y = c(58, 68, 78))

    counter <- reactiveVal(0)

    observeEvent(input$action, {
      if (counter() < 3) {
        counter(counter() + 1)
      } else {
        counter(1)
      }
    })

    rv_tibble <- reactive({
      slice(data, counter())
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot() +
        geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), size = 5) +
        geom_point(data = rv_tibble(), aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", size = 10)
    })
  },
  options = list(height = 600)
)
```
````

[image]